# Locating the row of a specific text/string in a specific column using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, excel, row

im new in Vb.net and would like to ask how to locate the exact row number of a specific string in a specific column. For example:

```
1 CEBE 
2 START
3 Aico, Pilar
4 END
```

In the above example i would like to get the row number of text/string START which is row 2, and END which is in row 4. How would i do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you didn't specify what type of row and column you're using, here's a rough idea: `Dim index As New List(Of Integer)()
For Each row As Object In something
 If row.text = "START" Or row.text = "END" Then
  index.Add(row.index)
 End If
Next`

Comment: this are general rows and column.

Comment: Okay, so the code sample should work if you substitute the type of columns and rows you use. Did you try it?

Comment: How to change the "in something" there to a column, like column B

Comment: I already tried the code but nothing seems happened

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't see you had the Excel tag. Instead of `in something` try `Excel.Range("B1", "B20")`, or whatever row and columns you need.

Answer (score 0):

Loop code count by column and row.

```
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim range As Excel.Range
    Dim rCnt As Integer
    Dim cCnt As Integer
    Dim Obj As Object

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\Schedule.xlsx")
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet1")

    range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange

    For rCnt = 1 To range.Rows.Count
        For cCnt = 1 To range.Columns.Count
            Obj = CType(range.Cells(rCnt, cCnt), Excel.Range)
            MsgBox(Obj.value)
        Next
    Next

    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()

    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
```

End Sub

```
Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
```